# Reference or value when stored in primitive types?

Tags: java

I'm new with java, have been mostly programming in C/C++ in the past.

I've been practicing on lint code.com lately,
and I came across some oddities in the interpretation of the same piece of code between my IDE(Android Studio) and the online judge system of lintcode.com.

So here's the code:

```
public class Solution{
    public int kthSmallest(int[][] matrix, int k) {
        int a = matrix[0][0];
        matrix[0][0] = 100;
        return a;
    }
}
```

Note that the input matrix is {{1,5,7},{3,7,8},{4,8,9}} and k is 4,
in Android Studio I get 1 as the return value,
on lintcode.com I get 100...

Since 'a' is a primitive type, I was expecting that it should only copy the value of matrix[0][0], but it seems to be storing it's reference instead,
which behaviour is correct? :S

Comment: Your expectation is correct.  I've never heard of Lintcode, but the site appears to be non-functional in Firefox.  Either that or their UI is just so horrible that I can't figure out how to use it.  I wouldn't trust them for anything.

Comment: Thanks, needed someone to back me up on my belief since I'm still a newbie.

Comment: Whatever "lintcode" is, it's probably calling your method `kthSmallest` twice and returning the result of the second call. Add some `System.err.println("Test Output");` to the method to see how often it is called.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> which behaviour is correct?

The value being stored is correct.

[Primitives vs References](http://pages.cs.wisc.edu/~hasti/cs302/examples/primitiveVsRef.html)